# Plotly choropleth can't read State iso codes

Tags: python, plotly, choropleth

I want to visualize the number of crimes by state using plotly express.
This is the code :

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.choropleth(grouped, locations="Code",
                    color="Incident",
                    hover_name="Code", 
                    animation_frame='Year',
                    scope='usa')
fig.show()
```

The dataframe itself looks like this:

[image]

I only get blank map:

[image]

**What is the wrong with the code?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the lack of color coding is that the United States is not specified in the location mode. please find attached a graph with locationmode='USA-states' added. You can find an [example](https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/#using-builtin-country-and-state-geometries) in the references. The data was created for your data.

```
df.head()
Year    Code    State   incident
0   1980    AL  Alabama     1445
1   1980    AK  Alaska  970
2   1980    AZ  Arizona     3092
3   1980    AR  Arkansas    1557
4   1980    CA  California  1614

import plotly.express as px

fig = px.choropleth(grouped,
                    locations='Code',
                    locationmode='USA-states',
                    color='incident',
                    hover_name="Code", 
                    animation_frame='Year',
                    scope="usa")
fig.show()
```

[image]